# Git on Azure DevOps tells me there are 100 commits to merge even though I only made a few changes

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a git repo on Azure DevOps and I'm trying to create a pull request, but when I do so, I see 100 commits in the log of what's going to be merged, even though I only made a few changes. This only happens when I create a PR into the development branch; it doesn't happen when I create a PR into the master branch. I already tried pulling development and merging it into my feature branch; what could be causing all these commits to clutter up my pull request? I also tried creating a brand new branch from development (thinking my original branch was stale) and cherry-picking the commit that I want to create the PR for, but I still get 100 commits! The really weird thing is that there are only a few files listed as changed, even with all those commits...

Comment: Can we safely guess your feature branch was created off `master` rather than `development`? If `master` is never merged back to `development` in your workflow, this is not unexpected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I created it from development; I even tried creating a brand new feature branch off of development, pasting my changes in there, and creating another PR, but that gave me the same results. Now I'm going to try cloning the repo from scratch again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do is start over from scratch and re-clone the repo, and paste my changes into a new feature branch from the newly cloned development branch.

Comment: That's great you fix it, You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),

Comment: Yep, I was going to do that but I was told I had to wait to do that, and then it slipped my mind...